# Is there functionality in magit, the emacs git add-on, to jump to edits?

Tags: git, emacs, elisp, emacs24, magit

In Jetbrains products, like IntelliJ and RubyMine, you can hit F4 in the diff window of a git diff to jump to to the current edit. Is there any functionality in Magit for emacs to go directly to a diff from git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magit does this by default pretty much everywhere. Just hit <kbd>RET</kbd> / <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to the source code for the current diff hunk.

`magit-visit-item` is the function.